# Android App uses device locale on orientation change instead of the forced locale

Tags: android

I have forced locale on my app by setting a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED`. If the user changes the locale and if my app is already launched it should NOT update to the new locale.

If I launch my app and then change the locale and open a new `Activity` from a `Button` click then the locale is maintained.

But If I change the orientation after launching the new `Activity` from the `Button` click then the device locale is used instead of the app.

Can anyone point out why that happens?

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest.xml you should define

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

for each of your activities.